# typeahead.js does not trigger source function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I am trying to integrate twitter typeahead.js, for this I downloaded the library from https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js and included `typeahead.bundle.min.js`

I then added the following

```
<input type="text" class="form-control typeahead font-normal">
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        console.log(query);
    }
});
```

The problem is it does trigger the source function, I am expecting that it prints the query in console. which it does not.

What could be possibly wrong here?

Thanks.

**Following solution worked.**

As pointed in the answer, I added the following library first

> 1. jquery.min.js
> 2. typeahead.bundle.min.js (https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)
> 3. typeahead.jquery.min.js (https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)
> 4. bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js (https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)

And then initialized the following code

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {  
        process([
            {id: "1", name: "Display name 1"},
            {id: "2", name: "Display name 2"}
        ]);
    }
});
```

And it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,
You have to add bootstrap typeahead js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
```

jsFiddle for the same
https://jsfiddle.net/aa7zyyof/17/

Comment: You are right, this gets triggered now, but when I try to return the JSON object, it does not display, how to display the result?

Comment: I got it, updating the question for reference. Thank you.

Comment: There is another "maintained" version of typeahead.js here...
https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js